# Non conducting charged planes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, capacitance

I have two parallel non conducting charged planes with opposite charges $6\mu C/m^2$, area $A = 3m^2$ and distance between the planes $d = 0.004 m$. I know the potential between these two planes is $$V = \frac{\sigma\times d}{\epsilon_0}$$
But if I put a conducting sheet of thickness $h = 0.001 m$ with the same area $A = 3m^2$ between these two planes, the new potential between the the planes would be

$$V = (2\times\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0} + 2\times\frac{2\sigma}{2\epsilon_0})\times d$$

Is this right? or Am I wrong somewhere? I mounted this schema.

[image]

Is that right?

Comment: Hi Joao. I think this slightly *disagrees* with our [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/11062)...

Comment: How can I improve the question? I tried to explain what I did with the image I posted.

Comment: That's why I mentioned *slightly*. Image isn't gonna provide you the answer anyway. When you try to explain what you've done, there will be **no** question like *"How can I calculate..."* It'd be actually, *"I did like this... Where am I getting wrong?"* <-- sorta something like that. I don't know. I don't make any decision. Maybe, someone could take a look ;-)

Comment: I posted a solution I've tried and I will do some changes like _"How can I calculate..."_

Comment: I think it's OK now. Hope you like the formatting ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charges on the conducting sheet will be $±\sigma$, not $±2\sigma$. Also, you will have to subtract the thickness of the conducting sheet, $h$ because $E$ is zero there.

So, your final equation should be $$V=(\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}+\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0})\times(d-h)$$

Comment: Dude, you shine!!